# Angular2 Component Instances with different CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular2 app with components, some of which I want to use multiple times on the same page. I originally had three components but in the spirit of refactoring I want to combine some of the functionality into one.

The basic HTML of the component is as follows:

```
<div class="component-class componentA-main" >
  <div class="result componentA">
    <div class="canvasContainer">
      ... common component functionality here ... 
      <canvas id="canvas_container"></canvas>
    </div>
  <div class="componentA-results">
    ... common component functionality here ... 
  </div>
</div>
```

The other two components have the same structure/functionality only with the CSS being different. Each component also has it's own CSS file.

The components would be used in the following way:

```
<div>
 <component id="ComponentA"></component>
 <component id="ComponentB"></component>
 <component id="ComponentC"></component>
</div>
```

Now my thinking here is to rename any component specific CSS classes to something generic and have three different component CSS files (componentA.css, componentB.css, etc.)

I'm however unsure how to make each instance of the component use the correct css. The only thing I was thinking about was something along the lines of:

```
 <component id="ComponentA" [css-main]='???' [css-result]='???'></component>
```

This however will become a mess using @Input which I don't feel should be used for styling anyway.

Is there a correct/better way of doing this or would best practice dictate that I'm expecting too much of a component and stick with 3 separate ones?

Thanks

Comment: I;m not sure what are you trying to achieve here. By default all components can have their own css with the `styleUrls` or `style` selectors. Can you explain further in order me to understand and provide you an answer?

Comment: I have added a usage case. I would like to have all instances of the component (components A, B, C) use a different CSS. I would however like to reuse the component itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the usage still but hre is my proposal based on your request. That is to use 'styleUrls' parameter and split your style in those style files.

Here's my example:

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-component_A.component.css','my-component_B.component.css']
})
...
```

You html:

```
<my-component id="component_A"></my-component>
<my-component id="component_B"></my-component>
```

You css.
**my-component_A.component.css**

```
:host
    #component_A
       background: red;
```

**my-component_B.component.css**

```
:host
    #component_B
       background: green;
```

Still though you can do similar things with the `ngClass` and `style` attributes.

Comment: Perfect! Glad to help.